# Appear Select dynamic on change other select Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have an error when making a dynamic select. My ajax doesn't work when I change my select.

This is the view code:

```
<%= select_tag 'cost', options_for_select(Cost.all.map { |c| ["#{c.types}", c.id] }),:id => "cost_select" %>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cost_select").live('change',function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: "finances/cost_type",
        type: "GET",
        data: {'cost=' + $('#cost_select option:selected').value() },
      })
    });
});
</script>
```

Im my finances controller, I have this:

```
def cost_type
  @places = Place.find_by_cost_id(params[:cost])
  respond_with @places
end
```

I make the `cost_type.js.erb` file, and my response is in js.

My problem is when i change the select tag dont active no one action, how is the problem whit the code in my searchs i find this code working but what is the problem?

UPDATE:

my routes.rb contains:

```
get "finances/cost_type" => "finances#cost_type"
```

---

I solved my original question with the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cost_select").change(function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: "finances/cost_type",
        type: "GET",
        data: {cost: $("#cost_select option:selected").val() },
      })
    });
});
```

With this, I received a valid response (which I verified via firebug):

```
$("#cost_select").after("<select id="from_money" name="from_money"><option value="2">Luz</option></select>
");
```

However, the data isn't appearing in my view. I tried putting it in a different `<div>` but the `<select>` won't appear.

I don't know what is wrong, please provide me with any possible suggestions.

Comment: Try using `data: {cost : $('#cost_select option:selected').value() }` in your ajax.

Comment: No works, dont works the event to change, dont appear nothing hm i update whit routes.rb

Comment: are you getting the value of cost in your action?

Comment: when i select i want the ajax not send the cost to controller, no active nothing when i change i view the console and nothing appear, i check my javascript i think is this, you question i dont understand sorry.

Answer (score 0):

change your javascript to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#cost_select").live('change',function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "/finances/cost_type",
      type: "GET",
      data: { cost: $('#cost_select').val() }
    })
  });
});
```

the extra `/` before finances makes sure that you're using absolute paths.  the `data` part is also wrong as pointed out in one of the comments but this is a cleaner version.